# Is there a way to pull a reservation that has been enqueued with one worker(waiting to be accepted), and assign it to yourself

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

Here is the scenario:
Call comes in. Agents A and B are available on the queue and eligible to take the call. TaskRouter assigns to Agent A, and Agent A's client gets the chance to accept it. For whatever reason Agent A does not pick it, and caller is on hold.

At the same time Agent B sees that there is a call waiting with Agent A(through statistics), and since he is free, would like to get the reservation re-assigned to himself. Is there a way to do this? Haven't so far been able to find anything in the docs that supports this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to directly change the reservation from one worker to another.

You could use the [REST API to trigger a manual rejection of the reservation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/reservations#code-reject-a-reservation). That would set the workflow to reserve a new worker for the task. However, in the case that you have more than 2 available agents there is no guarantee that the agent that was trying to claim the task will get it assigned. You also need to be careful, since tasks that are rejected 10 times are automatically cancelled.

Let me know if that helps at all.